# firebase MLKIT face detection camera resolution

Tags: java, android, firebase-mlkit

I am using a quickstart firebase MLKIT implementation with this link->
https://github.com/ankitjamuar/android-firebase-mlkit

but at the point when I found an image from the camera of MLKIT , it's resolution is 768*1024 .
but when I click the picture from my device native camera it gives me an 8 MP , i.e. 3264*2448 resolution image. so somehow I want to use this greater resolution image In MLKIT, which my device can capture as it's full capacity.so how can I increase MLKIT camera picture quality?

because when I get the face from the MLKIT camera picture, it also has low picture quality and I get lost my accuracy.One more thing here I am using the front camera for all.

please help, I got stuck , if possible I can get the accuracy for the face more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

check StillImageActivity.java

check line 352 and 353

targetWidth = isLandScape ? 1024 : 768;
 targetHeight = isLandScape ? 768 : 1024;

change the resolution as per your requirement.

Let me know if this solves your issue

Comment: hi thanx for response, I have changed the width and height as you say, but it does not affect the picture quality. I changed it to-> targetWidth = isLandScape ? 3264 : 2448; targetHeight = isLandScape ? 2448 : 3264.   when I see the implementation of the StillImageActivity.java class, nowhere in the MLKIT used this class.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the official [ML Kit Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit). The quickstart you link to is a pretty old fork.